# @rneui/base/dist/AirbnbRating/index could not be found within the project or in these directories:

Tags: react-native

The below code is resulting in the error:

@rneui/base/dist/AirbnbRating/index could not be found within the project or in these directories

This is not in my main App.js class but in a separate class.

I have imported the following library elements

import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {
LineChart,
BarChart,
PieChart,
ProgressChart,
ContributionGraph,
StackedBarChart,
} from 'react-native-chart-kit';

I have used the React Native Chart Kit documentation to

```
const barData = [{ value: 15 }, { value: 30 }, { value: 26 }, { value: 40 }];
return (
<View>
  <View>
    <Text>Bezier Line Chart</Text>
    <LineChart
      data={{
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
              Math.random() * 100,
            ],
          },
        ],
      }}
      width={Dimensions.get('window').width} // from react-native
      height={220}
      yAxisLabel="$"
      yAxisSuffix="k"
      yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
      chartConfig={{
        backgroundColor: '#e26a00',
        backgroundGradientFrom: '#fb8c00',
        backgroundGradientTo: '#ffa726',
        decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
        color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
        labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
        style: {
          borderRadius: 16,
        },
        propsForDots: {
          r: '6',
          strokeWidth: '2',
          stroke: '#ffa726',
        },
      }}
      bezier
      style={{
        marginVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: 16,
      }}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

);

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem like you
Unable to resolve "@rneui/base/dist/AirbnbRating/index" from "node_modules/@rneui/themed/dist/AirbnbRating/index.js"

This package sorted my problem:

```
   npm install @rneui/base @rneui/themed
```